# border-radius style not applied directly on the button but works via the specific class

Tags: css

In my HTML there are buttons inside of the table cells. All these buttons are supposed to be converted into circles by applying the border-radius style. In my css, I did the following

```
button{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

All other styles are applied to the buttons but not the border-radius. The only way I could get it to work was by assigning the HTML table a class & then using it in the css - something like this

```
.board button{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

Relevant HTML is

```
    <div>
      <table class='board'>
        <tr>
          <td><button type="button"></button></td>
          <td><button type="button"></button></td>
          <td><button type="button"></button></td>
          <td><button type="button"></button></td>
          <td><button type="button"></button></td>
          <td><button type="button"></button></td>
          <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Complete HTML & CSS are as below

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Connect Four Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Welcome to Connect Four!</h1>
      <h2>The object of this game is to connect four of your chips in a row!</h2>
      <h3>it is your turn, please pick a column to drop your chip</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <table class='board'>
        <tr>
          <td><button type="button"></button></td>
          <td><button type="button"></button></td>
          <td><button type="button"></button></td>
          <td><button type="button"></button></td>
          <td><button type="button"></button></td>
          <td><button type="button"></button></td>
          <td><button type="button"></button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <script src="practice.js">

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

css

```
h1, h2, h3{
  text-align: center;
}

h1{
  padding-top: 50px;
}

h3{
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

table{
  border: none;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

button{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

Result is

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbaT9.png)

Comment: Works fine for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am thinking that you have some specificity issues from other stylesheets.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, I've tried that on Chrome as well as FF - both latest.

Comment: @happymacarts, no other css is used in the project.

Comment: there is nothing in the code you have pasted here that would cause an issue. see the snippet below in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you posted the other code that revealed you are using Bootstrap I have identified your issue.

bootstrap uses a reset code

```
button {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

you have a few options.

**Sledgehammer approach**

```
button {border-radius: 50%;!important}
```

this approach while effective can have unwanted side-effects any time you want to override that you will also have to use an `!important` which can make maintenance a PITA (future you will appreciated NOT using !important)

**Loading your custom CSS after the bootstrap**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css">
```

**Use a custom class on your "button"** my preference

The class can be applied to the parent item as you did in your OP
or to the button itself like below

Using classes is what makes the CSS world go around. Don't be afraid to use them, they are your friends :)
when you are not using a class you are saying that every button that uses this style sheet will ALWAYS have those specs. but what happens when you add a form later with a submit button and you don't add a class - you get a 100px round button

```css
.btn-custom{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-custom"></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-custom"></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-custom"></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-custom"></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-custom"></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-custom"></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn-custom"></button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

*side note: for support in older browsers you may need a fallback*

```
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
```

Comment: I've just added complete HTML & CSS along with the resulting webpage's image - to the original question.

Comment: webkit & moz fallbacks didn't help either.

Comment: you mentioned you had no stylesheets but you are using `bootstrap`  and `practice.css` your issue is specificity. from those files. Yeah you can use a sledge-hammer approach and force it with !important but thats not always a good solution

Comment: My bad, didn't occur to me that bootstrap could be somehow overriding the styling here. 'practice.css' is the one where I am writing my styles.

Comment: I am editing my answer to more thuroughly explain

Comment: Although !important works, I'm all ears if you can share the ideal approach here & how to address such issues of specificity?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is problem that when you are applying border-radius on button it's not applying on button because there is  no parent of button
But when you are applying border-radius with parent class name than it will take % value  to the respective of there parent class
You can try it yourself by converting the border-radius from 50% to 50px. It will works perfectly.

Comment: Applying border-radius in px instead of % didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

One of your bootstrap styles is overriding your radius style. Add "!important" after radius and it works.

border-radius: 50% !important

Comment: this approach while effective can have unwanted side-effects any time you want to override that you will also have to use an `!important` which can make maintenance a PITA (future you will appreciated NOT using !important)

Comment: True, it's not a best practice to use !important. However, some situations, like using a CMS system such as Joomla where you have components that are continuously updated including new style sheets, it could be the only practical solution.